# Getting ANT to scp only new/changed files

Tags: ant, scp

I would like to optimize my scp deployment which currently copies all files to only copy files that have changed since the last build. I believe it should be possible with the current setup somehow, but I don't know how to do this.

I have the following:

Project/src/blah/blah/   <---- files I am editing (mostly PHP in this case, some static assets)

Project/build <------- I have a local build step that I use to copy the files to here

I have an scp task right now that copies all of Project/build out to a remote server when I need it.

Is it possible to somehow take advantage of this extra "build" directory to accomplish what I want -- meaning I only want to upload the "diff" between src/** and build/**. Is it possible to somehow retrieve this as a fileset in ANT and then scp that?

I do realize that what it means is that if I somehow delete/mess around with files on the server in between, the ANT script would not notice, but for me this is okay.

Comment: To clarify, I want it to basically do what the regular copy task does with incremental copying.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can tell `ant scp` to only copy files which have been modified since the last push using the `modified` tag like so:

```
<scp trust="true" sftp="true"... >
  <fileset dir="${local.dir}">
    <modified>
      <param name="cache.cachefile" value="localdev.cache"/>
    </modified>
  </fileset>
</scp>
```

The first time you use this, it will send all files and cache the timestamps in the cachefile declared in the `param`.  After that, it will only send the modified ones.

Tested and verified in sftp mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead. I found the following [article](http://joen.dk/wordpress/?p=34) that answers your question.

In a nutshell rsync will resume where it left off and it should be possible to tunnel it over ssh.